# cannot convert string to target type system nullable datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
public DateTime? SubscriptionStartDate { get; set; }
```

I want the datetime in string format after it has mapped a value:

```
SubscriptionStartDate = sheet.AUDIT_SHEET_SUBSCRIPTION_START_DATE
```

But i cant convert it to a string. I get the exception in my topic. I think i need to convert it to a non-nullable datetime object using the ?? operator, but im not sure how, since i never used it.

Comment: Hang on - you're assigning *to* SubscriptionStartDate... that means converting *to* a datetime, not *from* a datetime. It's not clear what you're really trying to do at the moment...

Comment: Which is it? Converting **to** a string or converting **from** a string?

Comment: typo, my bad. from datetime? to string

Comment: Can you update the title to match the body of the question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check it has a value, then you can get the tostring from it. e.g.:-

```
if(SubscriptionStartDate.HasValue)
{
    String myValue = SubscriptionStartDate.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to use + operator

```
public DateTime? SubscriptionStartDate { get; set; }

string result = "" + SubscriptionStartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a nullable issue per say.

Try (making sure to check for null first):

```
SubscriptionStartDate.parse( sheet.AUDIT_SHEET_SUBSCRIPTION_START_DATE )
```

( assuming you are retrieving a string and trying to assign a DateTime.... )

Comment: Im not recieving a string, im recieving a DateTime? and i want to convert it to a string.

Comment: SOrry, didnt see my typo, should be the opposite in the topic